# Hyperledger node.js failed to parse null

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

can somebody help with error which appears on HL Composer?
Error content: Error: SyntaxError: Failed to parse null: Unexpected token (377:39)
Line 377 is:  let exists = await accounts.exists(element.destinationAcc)

```
        
        let accounts = await getAssetRegistry(ns + '.Account');
        let transactions = await getAssetRegistry(ns + '.Transactions');

        let allTransactions = await query('pendingTransactions');
        let allAccounts = await accounts.getAll();
      
        if (allTransactions.length() > 0) {
            allTransactions.forEach(element => {
                if (element.status == 'PENDING') {
                    
                    let exists = await accounts.exists(element.destinationAcc);
                   
                    if (exists) {
                        
                        let destAcc = await allAccounts.find(element.destinationAcc);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard mistake that javascript developers make and isn't related to hyperledger composer at all.

You are trying to perform an `await` within a method that hasn't been declared `async`. HOWEVER even if you do add the keyword `async` to the method that you have declared inside the `forEach` declaration it still won't work, due to the way forEach works.

So for you the solution is, don't use the forEach method of an array to try to run an anonymous function with an `await` in it. Use an alternative method to iterate the allTransactions array such as a for loop.